# Inputing an array of arrays into a recurrent neural network (Keras)

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I currently have coordinate data in the form

```
coordinate = [x,y,z,t,dx,dy,dz,dt]
```

and groups of these coordinates form a path which looks something like this

```
path = [[coordinate 1], [coordinate2], ...]
```

and ultimately all my data is stored as a single array as an (array of an array of arrays) like this

```
data = [path1,path2,path3 ....]
```

I want to input a single path into Keras, specifically a LSTM to predict the next coordinate for that path. How can I do this? I know the time step is 1, and the batch size can vary to be None but Keras throws shape input errors.

At the moment my basic model is this (I'm aware that the options may not be correct)

```
model.add(LSTM(units=1,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(None,8)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#model.add(LSTM(units=1,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(None,8)))                                                                                                                                               
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))                                                                                                                                                                                           

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Thanks

Comment: Your shape must be `(pathes, coordinate_groups, coordinates=8)` -- Keras doesn't work with array of arrays. Only with single arrays. Your `input_shape` will work.

Comment: Thanks, for replying. I just want to check something. so my shape should be (number of paths, number of points in paths, number of coordinates)? Each path has a different number of points i.e., one path may only have 3 points and another may have 7? Would I have to train on a path by path basis such that my shape is then (number of paths = 1, number of hits for that path, coordinates=8)?

Comment: You can train one by one or you can create an array with "max hits" and use dummy values for the missing hits, together with a `Masking` layer at the beginning of the model to ignore the dummy values